# Angular: creating a custom directive that can call a scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a custom directive (let's call it MyDragSource) that can obtain its "drag context" by calling a function on the scope, like so:

```
<div my-drag-source drag-context="getDragContext">
```

In this case, getDragContext is a function that's defined on the scope:

```
$scope.getDragContext = function() { // return drag source }
```

I want getDragContext to be lazily invoked when the drag operation begins, not evaluated up front. How can I do this?

In my custom directive, I've tried the following:

```
$scope.$eval($attrs.dragContext);
```

However, that doesn't yield the desired result.

Comment: it's not going to be invoked until you actually execute it with `()`

Comment: can you show the code of the directive? right now you are assigning a property to a function, not the result of the function, but you appear to be trying to evaluate the variable inside the directive like it's outside on the scope....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the function as an attribute on your directive:

`<div my-drag-source drag-context="getDragContext()" >`

Use isolate scope in your directive, and import `dragContext` using `&`, which defines the scope property as a function that returns the results of evaluating the attribute's contents in the parent scope (in this case, `$scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.dragContext)`):

```
scope: {
  dragContext: '&'
}
```

Then you can call the function whenever you want in `link` function:

`$scope.dragContext()`

If you pass the method without parentheses, you can still call it from the `link` function, you just need to invoke the function, by adding another set of parens:

`$scope.dragContext()()`

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much! Just one minor correction: on the scope definition above, you need "dragContext:" rather than "drag-context:"

Comment: @Wolf Just be sure that you understand what the scope isolation does in this solution.

Comment: Just for correctness, & does not indicate a reference to an external function.  It is just shorthand for adding a function dragContext to the directive scope that returns $scope.$parent.$eval(atts.dragContext).  The expression attrs.dragContext can be any valid angular expression, not just a method invocation or method.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger thank you for providing this additional information, I will update

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this :

```
var data = $scope[$attrs.dragContext]();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fa68nhmr/)